# Trouble registering for Parse.com's push notification (Titanium / Android)

Tags: javascript, android, push-notification, parse-platform, titanium

How do I register my Titanium Android app for Parse' push notification. I have followed instructions from the [Parse Android Push Notification Guide](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) and done the following:

1. Created an installation record via POST to the Installation object
2. The App's AndroidManifest has the appropriate perms etc. based on Parse' Android Push notification guide

However, the push console still states that "Your application does not have any registered devices to which it can send notifications."

What am I missing? Do I need to enter my GCM Project Id anywhere or do something else? Any help / pointers will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For now, I have used Timan Rebel's very easy to use custom module that makes it happen in a few lines of code. Hopefully, someone will be able to offer other alternatives from a pure REST API perspective. Here is the link to the TiRebel's custom module on Github. https://github.com/timanrebel/Parse/tree/master/android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample repo here using the REST API for registering a device for push with Appcelerator, use the default function `Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications` but in the success callback used the `Parse.register` function included in the library below.

There is too much code to include it all here, but let me know if you have additional issues and I can update the answer

https://github.com/aaronksaunders/tiParsePushSample/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Saunders. I looked at the github repository and I think I understand what you did. It is unfortunate that Parse won't do much for Titanium users. BTW, I am a huge fan of your work with Titanium and have learnt a lot from your posts. Appreciate your help.